# regular expression for string in c

Tags: regex, string

I am working writing a regular expression used to validate string in C. Here is to what I have gone so far

```
'^"[A-Za-z0-9]*[\t\n]*"$'
```

for rules
- A string should begin with double quotes
- May not contain a newline character

However, I am not able to capture the rule for allowing '\' or '"' in a string if preceded with '\'. Here is what I tried:

```
'^"[A-Za-z0-9]*[\t\n]*[\\\|\\"]?"$'
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What might be wrong with the regular expression here?

Regards,
darkie15

Comment: What language are you doing the regex from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want this regular expression:

```
^"[A-Za-z0-9]*[\t\n]*"$
```

To notate in C you must have double quotes around the string. Then you must escape the escapes and the double quotes inside the expression.

Here's what you might have:

```
"^\"[A-Za-z0-9]*[\\t\\n]*\"$"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're misusing character classes and alternations in group; `[\\\|\\"]` isn't what you think it is.

Try something like this:

```
^"([A-Za-z0-9\t]|\\\\|\\")*"$
```

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html), [grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)